# Google Calendar API returning unauthorized even when domain is properly registered

Tags: php, push-notification, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using the google php client library to create a webhook to my domain, but the API keeps returning unauthorized.

I've successfully followed the steps on "registering your domain" on [push](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push) and my domain is listed on the API console.

Under APIs & Service > Domain verification it lists my domain under "allowed domains".

Yet it's still telling me the domain is unauthorized:

The library function

```
$channel = new Google_Service_Calendar_Channel();
$channel->setId($channelId);
$channel->setType("web_hook");
$channel->setAddress("https://example.com/notifications");
$service->events->watch($calendarId, $channel);
```

Error message

```
{ "error":
  { "errors": [{
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized", 
    "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://example.com/notifications"
    }],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://example.com/notifications"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google_Service_Calendar_Channel requires that you send a client to authenticate it. Personally i would use service account.

```
function getServiceAccountClient() {
    try {   
        // Create and configure a new client object.        
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');
        return $client;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

$client = getServiceAccountClient();
$channel = new Google_Service_Calendar_Channel($client);
$channel->setId($channelId);
$channel->setType("web_hook");
$channel->setAddress("https://example.com/notifications");
$service->events->watch($calendarId, $channel);
```

Comment: I've added the client in the channel creation like this:
`$channel = new Google_Service_Calendar_Channel($googleCalendar->getClient());`
But I still get the same error

Comment: Appears I had to create a OAuth2 client ID on the Google Developer Console, and then use that to authenticate my app.
After that, using the client made it works perfectly, thanks for the help!